# What is the "\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler", "Regular Maintenance" task in Windows 8.1?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, scheduled-tasks, wmi

I've been looking for tasks in Windows 8.1 that can wake my system from sleep and found this task:

[image]

Does anyone know what this `\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler`, `"Regular Maintenance"` task is?

PS. The weird thing about it is that every time I read it (either via WMI or through the Task Scheduler UI) I get a new run time for it.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About this ["Regular Maintenance" task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And there are [settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799178) that allow this event to wake up system from sleep.

About the random scheduled time, looks like it is by design. Although it is scheduled to run at 3:00 PM, the actually run time is randomized at some time near 3:00 PM. Think about an enterprise with thousands of computers, what happen if all commuters go into "Regular Maintenance" at exactly the same time?

Comment: Good info. Thanks. Just curious, if there's a task specific property in `ITaskSettings` or `IRegisteredTask` that makes the wake time `random`?

Comment: TimeTrigger has a `RandomDelay` property, but I am not sure since I have not used these interfaces in my code ever.

Comment: Thanks again. Here's the link that shows how to get to it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383624(v=vs.85).aspx